# Injecting custom model binders with structuremap 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I've found several guides on injecting custom model binders in `ASP.NET MVC` project using `StructureMap` and followed along this tutorial: http://benfoster.io/blog/model-binder-dependency-injection-structuremap

I installed `StructureMap.MVC5` package. And added the type binding inside the default registry:

```
public class DefaultRegistry : Registry {
    public DefaultRegistry() {
        Scan(scan => {
            scan.Assembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
        });

        For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(MongoDbRepository<>));

        var dictionary = new ModelBinderMappingDictionary();
        dictionary.Add<Car, CarModelBinder>();

        For<ModelBinderMappingDictionary>().Use(dictionary);
        For<IModelBinderProvider>().Use<StructureMapModelBinderProvider>();
    }
}

public class StructureMapModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider {
    private readonly IContainer container;

    public StructureMapModelBinderProvider(IContainer container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType) {
        var mappings = container.GetInstance<ModelBinderMappingDictionary>();
        if(mappings != null && mappings.ContainsKey(modelType))
            return container.GetInstance(mappings[modelType]) as IModelBinder;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` which points to the line:

```
var mappings = container.GetInstance<ModelBinderMappingDictionary>();
```

And these inner exception text:

> StructureMap.SessionCache.GetDefault(Type pluginType, IPipelineGraph pipelineGraph) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\SessionCache.cs:43
>      StructureMap.Container.GetInstance(Type pluginType) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:331
>      StructureMap.Container.GetInstance() in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:201
>      my_project_name.StructureMapModelBinderProvider.GetBinder(Type modelType) in d:\projects\unicorn\unicorn.web\infrastructure\model_binding\StructuremapModelBinderProvider.cs:15
>      System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderProviderCollection.GetBinder(Type modelType) +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderDictionary.GetBinder(Type modelType, IModelBinder fallbackBinder) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderDictionary.GetBinder(Type modelType, Boolean fallbackToDefault) +71
>      and so on...

What is wrong with that code?

Comment: Have you tried debugging GetBinder method and checking which part is behaving differently as expected?

Comment: No, I haven't done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it!

I tried to use another lifecycle type for `StructureMapModelBinderProvider`:

```
public class ModelBindingRegistry : Registry {
    public ModelBindingRegistry() {
        Scan(scan => {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
        });

        var dictionary = new ModelBinderMappingDictionary();
        dictionary.Add<Car, CarModelBinder>();

        For<ModelBinderMappingDictionary>().Use(dictionary);
        For<IModelBinderProvider>().Singleton().Use<StructureMapModelBinderProvider>();
    }
}
```

With `Singleton` it all works! Not sure whether `Singleton` scope is a good fit here though?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to register ModelBinderMappingDictionary as retrun value from Add method which is void.
Try this (DefaultRegistry):

```
    var modelBinderMappingDictionary = new ModelBinderMappingDictionary();
    modelBinderMappingDictionary.Add<Car, CarModelBinder>();
    For<ModelBinderMappingDictionary>().Use(modelBinderMappingDictionary);
```

Comment: I use chaining aka `return this` inside `Add` method. It would be impossible to compile though. That's not the problem. See my edit, please.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part.